# NSTimer only counting down seconds?

Tags: nstimer

My NSTimer is working but only counting down seconds? The minutes show up as "00" and the seconds count down, minutes stay at zero. The int countdownInt comes from user input and I have been testing by entering "45" for a 45 minute count down timer. The only thing that happens is that the seconds are counting down from "45"? countdownInt, seconds and minutes have all been declared int in the .h file

Thanks for your help!

```
 countdownInt -=1;
 seconds = countdownInt % 60;
 minutes = (countdownInt / 60) % 60;
countdownTimerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want user input to be in minutes, you should probably multiply it by 60 before you start decrementing seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is the countDownInt (in minutes), then

```
int countDownIntSeconds = countDownInt;

countDownIntSeconds -= 1;
seconds = countDownIntSeconds;
minutes = countDownIntSeconds % 60;
countdownTimerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
```